# Attaching Excel Files

Tags: discussion, support

> Is it possible to attach a excel file? Maybe as a website link?

On [my question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40709/alphabetical-sudoku) I have a Sudoku and have created an excel version but don't know how to attach it

Answer (score 6):

The only way I know of is to link to Dropbox or some other file sharing site.

You may also want to consider using Google Sheets - that way, it's collaboratively editable.